# Can "comply with" here be replaced by "abide by"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrases

The key explains that when using the phrase "abide by" you must ensure that "a person" serves as the subject of the sentence. Is that true?

- 6 All the activities of a joint venture shall ____ the provision of laws, decrees and pertinent regulations of the People's Republic of China.

a obey ... b abide by ... c comply with ... d observe

[[istack:imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7V3R.jpg)]

Comment: I would argue that B and C are equally valid in this context.

Comment: 'Abide by' can be replaced by 'live according to'. Does that work here? 'Comply with' allows a broader range of subject referents – the sizes of professional soccer pitches have to comply with (satisfy) certain regulations, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

[Pictures](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=activities%20must%20abide%20by%2Cactivities%20must%20obey%2Cactivities%20must%20comply%20with%2Cactivities%20must%20observe&year_start=1910&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cactivities%20must%20abide%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cactivities%20must%20obey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cactivities%20must%20comply%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cactivities%20must%20observe%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cactivities%20must%20abide%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cactivities%20must%20obey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cactivities%20must%20comply%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cactivities%20must%20observe%3B%2Cc0) are always useful...

[image]

---

As suggested by Řídící, at least *part* of the reason ***abide by, observe, obey*** rarely occur in such contexts is because those verbs are more strongly associated with *deliberate actions by sentient subjects*.

But part of the reason is just "established custom & practice". I'd also add that [formal *legal* contexts](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=document%20abides%20by%2Cdocument%20obeys%2Cdocument%20complies%20with%2Cdocument%20observes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdocument%20obeys%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdocument%20complies%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdocument%20observes%3B%2Cc0) are more likely to favour ***compliance*** (with laws) as opposed to formal *religious* contexts where you'll more often see references to ***observance*** (of rituals and rites).

---

It's really just *preference,* though - there's no absolute principle of vocabulary or syntax requiring or debarring any particular verb form in such contexts, so it's misleading to present this as "test material" with right and wrong answers. It would be pedantic in the extreme to complain about, [for example](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22administrative%20actions%20abide%20by%20due%20process%22),...

> *There are various mechanisms for making sure that **administrative actions abide by due process** and are explicitly justified*

Answer (score 0):

> Can “comply with” here be replaced by “abide by”?

No, because:

> The key explains that when using the phrase "abide by" you must ensure that "a person" serves as the subject of the sentence. Is that true?

Yes, I think that makes sense. *Abide by* means something like *accept and follow*, where *acceptance* is a mental state of sorts. Activities have no mental state. It has to be some person (or group or entity or maybe a smart animal or *perhaps* even something like a philosophy etc.) that does the accepting, and thus the abiding.